# Como fazer teste de carga do SignalR?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Ao fazer testes com a biblioteca `SignalR` para criar aplicações em real time em .NET, gerou-se algumas dúvidas sobre escalabilidade as quais não foram possíveis achar na internet.

Após alguns testes [usando o Crank](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Crank) (simulador de carga), vi que um servidor relativamente fraco comporta 100 conexões simultâneas, entrando no site em bandos de 10, permanecendo 120 segundos conectado.

- 6 mensagens por segundo, a CPU chegou a 60%
- 12 mensagens por segundo, a CPU bateu 100%

Mas estes testes não são muito confiáveis. Como eu posso efetivamente fazer um teste de carga com `SignalR` sem usar o `Crank`?

Comment: Dorival, duas perguntas: 1. você já tentou fazer um teste você mesmo, no braço? 2. O SignalR tem uma [library](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/samples/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.LoadTestHarness) própria relativamente madura. Já li sobre ela, mas nunca usara. Você a conhece?

Comment: Podias dizer também que servidor web usas-te para testar? Eu não uso SignalR, uso o Tornado em Python (que comunica com uma APP .NET por sub/pub do Redis) mas de qualquer forma 100 parece um número demasiado baixo, mesmo para o apache

Answer (score 4):

Eu pegaria uma biblioteca de websocket client (ex.: https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperWebSocket) e faria o teste manualmente.

É importante lembrar que a máquina que faz a requisição não pode ser a mesma que a recebe, pois isso geraria carga extra na CPU e utilizaria mais portas (lembrando que o total de portas abertas é de no máximo ~64000).

Tente também realizar testes em métodos que não fazem nada (se quiser testar a escalabilidade do SignalR/WebSockets e não seu código)